# Is there an equivalent of truffle's deployer.link() functionality without using truffle?

Tags: truffle

I'm trying to migrate a project away from using Truffle, and in the migration script, it currently uses truffle's `link()` function. Is there some sort of equivalent library, perhaps implemented by web3 or ethers.js that handles this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use solc's linker https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc#linking-bytecode

It should give you the tools for linking contracts.